# list-reset doesn't work to get rid of list

Tags: html, css

I wanna get rid of markers of list but list-reset doesn't work. What is wrong? I don't wanna use something else but list reset, it's important

```css
.list-reset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="Konstruct logo black"></a>
    <ul class="navbar list-reset">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. Your html looks broken by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a starting nav element `<nav>`. This may be the problem.

```
<section class="navbar">
         <div class="container">
            <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="Konstruct logo black"></a>
     <nav>      
            <ul class="navbar list-reset">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

This should be the correct HTML structure.

Comment: Oh maybe but there was <nav> but the result was the same and then I decided to remove <nav> but forgot about closing tag. But anyway with it or without the result is the same...